# PyQt5 delayed signal (at the start of next loop of event loop)

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt5

I'm trying to implement delayed signals in PyQt5. I want to define a function, which should execute at the start of the next PyQt5 main event loop. I want that because I want to do something after return from call stack in my Application.

Is it possible to add some handler to the start or end of PyQt5 event loop?

I tried to use `QEventLoop` class, but there is no possibility to do something before/after each loop.

Thanks

Comment: Could you explain me better, maybe an MCVE better illustrate the problem. Maybe what you want is not possible and that would indicate that you have an [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/), why do you want to implement this functionality?

Comment: I have an application. Based on button clicked, AI starts playing. If AI destroys some unit, the game is over. The user then could select an action, for example, restart the game. But I am inside the loop. If I restart the game now (delete all object), I could not finish AI turn (because of history I want to finish that round). So I want to restart the game after this is finished. I could do something after clicking on the button, but there is a problem that this signal could be invoked from more places. For code readability, I want to implement this with the delayed event.

Comment: Yes please provide attempted examples of code and before/after explanation of what you want to occur.

Comment: @JanHoráček I think your strategy is wrong, what you should do is have a flag that indicates that the game is over, and so when the button is pressed, change the state of that flag, and then check the flag when the AI finishes its turn. Do not you think this is the simplest?

Comment: @eyllanesc Yes I really want to do that, only one problem is that there is not one place, where to do that. So that is why I want to do it with delayed events. But if it is not possible, I will add the restart condition to all top-level places.  I just want to know, if something like a delayed event is possible in PyQt5.

Comment: is that you do not have to refer to a delayed signal, the event loop will call the associated slot when he can, that is, there is no guarantee in general of when he called the function since many times he will invoke other functions that are in the tail, remember the eventloop has other tasks than the signals, do not complicate and use the simple solution. It is also difficult to understand without a mcve

Comment: Ok. Thanks for the explanation. I will do it a simple way.